# regex one dot or one underline validator

Tags: regex, validation, zend-validate

this is my regex

```
^(([a-z0-9]+)\.([a-z0-9]+)){4,20}$|^(([a-z0-9]+)\_([a-z0-9]+)){4,20}$
```

it's gonna be a word with a single dot OR a single underline OR no uderline and dot. i also want this expression between 4 and 20 chars (it's gonna be a username in db)

this regex

```
^(([a-z0-9]+)\.([a-z0-9]+))$
```

and this one

```
^(([a-z0-9]+)\_([a-z0-9]+))$
```

works successfully but i dont know how to limit the string length

:( help please

im gonna be using it with zend framework regex validator ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
^(?=[^\._]+[\._]?[^\._]+$)[\w\.]{4,20}$
```

Explanation:

```
^            - Start of string
(?=          - Followed by (not part of match)
  [^\._]+    - Anything but . and _
  [\._]?     - Optional . or _
  $          - End of string
)
[\w\.]{4,20} - 4-20 letters, digits, _ and .
$            - End of string
```

The `(?=[^\._]+[\._]?[^\._]+$)` ensures that the string contains no more than 1 `.` or `_`. The rest matches the string.

Comment: I added an explanation. See also: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Very minor note - you don't need to escape the period inside a character class.

Comment: @Mike: Noted. I prefer escaping over not escaping when both are an option, to prevent confusion.

Comment: One could argue that escaping is always an option I guess, but I think I understand your point.

Comment: sorry it is late to say it, the string doesn't have to have a dot or underline, the string "foofoo" is just valid and should match.

Answer (score 2):

You should validate the length with a second validator, rather than in the regular expression, as this will improve the readability of your code.  Use `^[a-z0-9]+[._][a-z0-9]+$` as your regular expression with the [Regex](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.regex) validator, and use the [StringLength](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.stringlength) validator to check the length.

Comment: it can be like this and its almost over :D
`^[a-z0-9]+([._]{0,1})[a-z0-9]+$`

Comment: Just an FYI - this is a shorter version of that regex: `^[a-z0-9]+[._]?[a-z0-9]+$` (the ? is equivalent to {0,1} and parentheses are not required).